# How to correctly send application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Angular post call

Tags: angular, paypal, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get Paypal access token and according to paypal, the data of the request is `-d "grant_type=client_credentials"` and have to send it in a application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, Below is the code that I'm trying now

```
let body = "grant_type=client_credentials"

return this.httpClient.post<any (`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token`,body);
```

and I'm setting the header in the auth interceptor like below

```
const copiedReq = req.clone({ 
    setHeaders: {
      'Authorization': `Basic  ${this.client_id}:${this.secrete}`, 
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
});
return next.handle(copiedReq);
```

it always returning 401 Unauthorized but my `client_id` and `secrete` is okay because when I try the call with postman it's working fine

## The Network Tab

[image: The network tab]
it's working fine on the postman with same credential, but not here, what I'm doing wrong? How can I make a proper request to get the result

## The Paypal curl example

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "client_id:secret" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better late than never. I just had the same problem than you and I finally solved it.
You have to base 64 encode your credentials:

```
let credentials: btoa(`${this.client_id}:${this.secrete}`);

const copiedReq = req.clone({ 
setHeaders: {
  'Authorization': `Basic  `+credentials, 
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
});
return next.handle(copiedReq);
```

This just worked for me a few minutes ago. Hope it works for you next time :D

Comment: Nice! Vote up the answer mate ! So others can apply it :D